# Google App Engine: Backend getting stuck after fetching a large number of URLs

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm having a problem with the GAE backends and taskqueues. Basically what happens is, after the backend does several url fetch calls for a few minutes, tasks start getting stuck without even starting. The enforced rate drops to 0.10/s and the queue hardly moves. It only starts to move if I restart the Backend instance but only to reach the 0.10/s enforced rate again.

I'm currently working on a GAE project that requires the app to traverse around 70000 URLs, retrieve the HTML, check for values in the HTML, and update some records in the datastore based on the values in the HTML.

The implementation involves a cron job that takes around 300 URLs every minute, splits them by 10's, and assigns them to different tasks in the task queue. Each task goes through their 10 URLs, processing the contents.

I'm running a B4 static backend instance. Task queue rate is at 5/s. Max concurrent requests is 8.
I tried adding task aging as well but it didn't help.

---- October 19, 2013 ----

Edit: I tried commenting out a lot of code and narrowed down the problem to URL Fetching. Apparently when I remove the URL fetching, things run very smoothly. Still, I'm not sure how to fix this since I'm pretty sure I closed all connection related resources.

Answer (score 0):

You may reach [the quota limit for URL fetch](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#UrlFetch) which is 3000 API calls/minute or 657,000 API calls/day.